# Why does Passport retry the authentication when it fails to connect?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ldapauth

I have a Node.js & Express app, using [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) and [passport-ldapauth](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth) for LDAP authentication.

Everything works OK... unless it fails connecting to the LDAP server (it may be offline, or the IP address be wrong, etc.). In that case, `passport.authenticate` is somehow executed twice (I just can't figure out why), and as a result, I get `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`.

These are the relevant parts of my server.js and routes.js:

```js
// Import modules
var express      = require('express');
var session      = require('express-session');
var passport     = require('passport');
var passportLdap = require('passport-ldapauth');

// Configure Express, session suppport, and Passport
var app = express();
app.use(session({ resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, secret: 'foo' }));
passport.use('ldap', new passportLdap({server: { /* LDAP settings */ }}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routings
app.get('/login', function(req, res) { res.render('loginForm.ejs'); });
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('ldap', {session: true}, function(err, user, info) {
        if (err || !user) {
            console.log(err ? 'ERROR' : 'CREDENTIALS');
            res.status(403).render('loginForm.ejs', {message: err || 'Wrong credentials!'});
        } else {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
            res.redirect('/home');
        }
    })(req, res);
});
```

If the authentication is successful, the console only shows `SUCCESS`.

If the user enters either a wrong username or password, it shows `CREDENTIALS`, and the login form is loaded again, displaying the "Wrong credentials!" message. No errors appear on the console.

However, if the LDAP server is down, **I get `ERROR` *twice* on the console**. (Why?!) Then obviously, as it's doing a second `res.render` with the same response object, I get the `Can't set headers after they are sent` error. And since it's the second attempt that fails, the user still gets the form login with the proper error message (which was rendered on the first attempt).

If I change my `if (err)` block to do `next(err)` instead of `res.render()`... I don't get the headers problem, but still, the exception with the LDAP (for example "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND") is shown twice on the console, as if Passport was retrying after the first attempt.

Also, I have noticed there is a [`handleErrorsAsFailures`](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth#configure-strategy) option in ldapauth. If I enable it, then it shows `CREDENTIALS` twice on the console for connection problems, and only once if I actually input wrong credentials.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a *(hopefully temporal?)* workaround, I've changed my code to this:

```js
if (err || !user) {
    if (!res.headersSent) { // <---------- CHECK TO PREVENT THE ISSUE ---------
        console.log(err ? 'ERROR' : 'CREDENTIALS');
        res.status(403).render('loginForm.ejs', {message: err || 'Wrong credentials!'});
    }
} else // ...
```

Which prevents the second render attempt, and avoids the `Can't set headers after they are sent` error.

I still have no clue of what's causing this behaviour or how to fix it, though...

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to wrap all the code in the route with an if-else statement:

```
    if(res.headersSent) {
       return;
    } else {
      *//the rest of the code goes here*
    }
```